# Return result of process after an exception is triggered

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing setup that handles a long running task by appending all calculated values to `lst`. It looks roughly like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep


def fun(_):
    lst = []  # list that will be returned
    for i in range(200):
        lst.append(i)
        if not i % 10:
            sleep(0.1)  # 'long task', cause a KeyboardInterrupt in this time
    return lst


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = []
    processes = 2
    for result in Pool(processes).imap_unordered(fun, range(processes)):
        master.append(result)
    print(master)
```

I want to be able to cause a `KeyboardInterrupt` and have the processes return the list they worked on, even if they are not done yet, as each iteration just adds a new sublist.
(My actual data looks roughly like `lst = ([], [[], ...], [[], ...])`, every empty list contains ints only, the actual function would `return lst1, lst2, lst3`)

I have tried to envelop the whole main part in `try: except:` like so:

```py
try:
    for result in Pool(processes).imap_unordered(fun, range(processes)):
        master.append(result)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # somehow retrieve the values here
    pass
```

I have however not come to any possible solution this way.
How can I tell the processes it's time to exit early and return me their current result?

Edit to show the actual structure:
main.py:

```py
from other import Other

class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # stuff here
    
    def spawner(self):
        for result in Pool(processes=self.processes).imap_unordered(self.loop, range(self.processes)):
            pass  # do stuff with the data

    def loop(self, _):
        # setup stuff
        Other(setup_stuff).start()
```

other.py

```py
class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # more stuff

    def start(self):
        lst1, lst2, lst3 = [], [], []
        for _ in range(self.episodes):
            pass  # do the actual computation
        return lst1, lst2, lst3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of a `list` to return variables. Set-up one queue at the beginning and all processes will write to the queue.

At the end, read all values from the queue.

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

q = None


def set_global_data(queue):
    global q
    q = queue


def fun(_):
    for i in range(200):
        q.put_nowait(i)
        if not i % 10:
            sleep(0.1)  # 'long task', cause a KeyboardInterrupt in this time
    # nothing is returned


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Queue()
    processes = 2

    try:
        with Pool(processes, set_global_data, (master,)) as p:
            for result in p.imap_unordered(fun, range(processes)):
                pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    while not master.empty():
        v = master.get_nowait()
        print(v)
```

---

EDIT: With multiple files:

#### main.py

```py
from other import Other
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # stuff here

    def spawner(self):
        master = Queue()

        try:
            with Pool(2, Something.set_global_data, (master,)) as p:
                for _ in p.imap_unordered(self.loop, range(2)):
                    pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

        while not master.empty():
            v = master.get_nowait()
            print(v)

    def loop(self, _):
        # setup stuff
        Other().start()

    @staticmethod
    def set_global_data(queue):
        Other.q = queue


s = Something()
s.spawner()
```

#### other.py

```py
from time import sleep


class Other:
    q = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass  # more stuff

    def start(self):
        for i in range(200):
            Other.q.put_nowait(i)
            if not i % 10:
                sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: This does seem to work, however I failed to describe that the actual computation takes place in a different file, so `global q` does not work. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ArcKoor See my edit.

Comment: Well done, thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrejKesely best practice to get all results from queue inside `with Pool` context, and not to trust `queue.empty()`. Otherwise deadlocks or missed data can occur. Also "main.py" example is missing import protection for running with a "spawn" context.